# Incrementing in a dictionary

Tags: python, duplicates

I've seen a bunch of posts that do basically what I'm doing, but unfortunately I'm not sure why I keep getting output that is not what I want. The problem is that I am trying to increment a dictionary every time a certain word appears in my excel file, but every instance of a word is treated as a new word as my code currently is. For example "the" occurs ~50 times in my file, but the output just lists "the" on many different lines with a count of "1" for each instance. When in reality I want "the" to be listed once, with a count of "50".  Would greatly appreciate any clarification!  Here is my code:

```
import csv
import string

filename = "input.csv"
output = "output1.txt"

def add_word(counts, word):
    word = word.lower()
    #the problem is here, the following line never runs
    if counts.has_key(word):
        counts[word] +=1
    #instead, we always go to the else statement...
    else:
        counts[word] = 1
    return counts

def count_words(text):
    word = text.lower()
    counts = {}
    add_word(counts, word)
    return counts

def main():
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    input_fields = ('name', 'country')
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = input_fields)
    next(reader)
    first_row = next(reader)
    outfile = open(output, "w")
    outfile.write("%-18s%s\n" %("Word", "Count"))
    for next_row in reader:
        full_name = first_row['name']
        word = text.split(' ',1)[0]
        counts = count_words(word)
        counts_list = counts.items()
        counts_list.sort()
        for word in counts_list:
            outfile.write("%-18s%d\n" %(word[0], word[1]))
        first_row = next_row

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using plain dictionaries, the *dict.get* method is well suited to counting:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for color in 'red green blue green red red green'.split():
        d[color] = d.get(color, 0) + 1

>>> d
{'blue': 1, 'green': 3, 'red': 3}
```

The [collections module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#module-collections) offers two ways of simplifying this code.

Here's one using [*collections.Counter*](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter()
>>> for color in 'red green blue green red red green'.split():
        d[color] += 1

>>> d
Counter({'green': 3, 'red': 3, 'blue': 1})
```

And there is the [*collections.defaultdict*](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) approach:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for color in 'red green blue green red red green'.split():
        d[color] += 1

>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'blue': 1, 'green': 3, 'red': 3})
```

The regular dictionary approach is most suitable when your output needs to be a regular dictionary or when you're using an older version of Python.

The *Counter* approach is easy-to-use and has a number of utilities well-suited to counting applications (for example, the most_common() method lists the *n* biggest counts in sorted order).  A [backport of Counter](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/) is available for versions of Python prior to 2.7.

The *defaultdict* approach has some disadvantages.  Merely accessing a missing value will cause the dictionary to grow.  Also, to use it, you need to understand factory functions and know that *int()* can be called with no arguments to produce a zero value.

Comment: The `Counter` example can be simplified to: `d=Counter('red green blue breen red red green'.split())`

Comment: When you teach people how to use Counter, that is not the first thing you teach.  Start with ``c[k]+=1`` and work your way up.

Comment: Should also be mentioned that `Counter` is only for Python 2.7+

Comment: @RaymondHettinger:  I think that ignores one of the main utilities of `Counter`, which is to avoid having to write any sort of loop.  (The other nice part of `Counter` you already mention -- it "as a number of utilities well-suited to counting applications".)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- I always found it very confusing about the python documentation.  starting with `c[k] += 1` really doesn't distinguish a counter from a `defaultdict` at all.  In fact, for a long time I (mistakenly) thought, "why do I need `Counter`?  It's just a `defaultdict`" ...

Comment: Regarding `defaultdict`,  I sometimes set the `default_factory` attribute to `None` to avoid growing the dictionary when accessing missing keys.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger, thanks for the help! I found the regular dictionary approach the easiest for now, but will come back to this page when I know more so I can better understand the other approaches. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Your function `count_words` is creating a new dictionary every time it is called (as opposed to just adding to the current `results` dictionary.

However, for something like this, you might want to consider using a `Counter` (which is a special `dict` in the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for row in csv_reader:
    c.update(text.lower() for text in row)

print(c)
```

Comment: @user1590499 -- See my edit using a `Counter`.  Hopefully that will be enough to get you where you want to be ...

Comment: For those who are inordinately fond of one-liners: `c = Counter(text.lower() for row in in csv_reader for text in row)`

Comment: Ha!  I did say "inordinately".  However, I would write such a line assuming it was assigned name like `word_count`.  I'd write one line for opening the file, another for creating the csv reader, and then a final line `word_count = Counter(s.lower() for row in reader for s in row)`.